# Return function that modifies the value of the input function

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

How can I make a function that is given a function as input and returns a function with the value tripled. Here is some pseudo code for what I'm looking for. Concrete examples in Python or Scala would be appreciated.

```
def f(int x):
    return x ** 2

def tipleFunc(Function g)
    return 3 * g

Function newFunc = tripleFunc(f)
print newFunc(5)
```

Comment: IMO, Python *should* support something like that. `__mul__` isn't defined at all for functions ATM, and there isn't really another obvious interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 2

def tripleFunc(g):
    return lambda *args: 3 * g(*args)

newFunc = tripleFunc(f)
print newFunc(5)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can return a function to pass x into or do I have to just pass it the function and any arguments it might need?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala:

```
def foo(x: Int) = x * x
def quadruple(f: Int => Int) = (x: Int) => 4 * f(x)
val quadfoo = quadruple(foo)
scala> quadfoo(3)
res0: Int = 36
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `@decorator` syntax to do this; `@decorator` is equivalent to assigning `somefunc = decorator(somefunc)`, allowing an arbitrary wrapper function to be applied:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def multiplier(n):
    """Create a decorator to multiply a wrapped function's output by n."""
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f) # retain the wrapped function's docstring
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            return n * f(*args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return wrapper

>>> @multiplier(3) # apply a multiplier of 3 to the outputs of f
def f(x):
    """Return x squared."""
    return x ** 2

>>> f(5)
75
```

Note the `*args, **kwargs` syntax to handle arbitrary arguments (positional and keyword, respectively). You can also create the `triple_func` decorator directly, e.g.:

```
>>> triple_func = multiplier(3)
>>> @triple_func
def f(x):
    """Return x squared."""
    return x ** 2

>>> f(5)
75
```

or even apply it without the decorator syntax at all:

```
>>> def f(x):
    """Return x squared."""
    return x ** 2

>>> new_func = triple_func(f) # or 'new_func = multiplier(3)(f)'
>>> new_func(5)
75
```